# Clear JTextField Contents on Click

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So I've built a very basic Web browser - I'm trying desperately to remove the contents of the address bar when a user clicks on it (`JTextField`) this appears with some text in as default.  Any advice is appreciated.

Have a great day!

MY CODE

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Web_Browser extends JFrame {

    private final JTextField addressBar;
    private final JEditorPane display;

    // Constructor 
    public Web_Browser() {
        super("Web Browser");

        addressBar = new JTextField("Click & Type Web Address e.g. http://www.google.com");        
        addressBar.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                           loadGo(event.getActionCommand());
                    }
                }
        );
        add(addressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        display = new JEditorPane(); 
        display.setEditable(false);
        display.addHyperlinkListener(
                new HyperlinkListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event){
                        if(event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED){
                            loadGo(event.getURL().toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        add(new JScrollPane(display), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(500,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    // loadGo to sisplay on the screen
    private void loadGo(String userText) {
        try{
           display.setPage(userText);
           addressBar.setText(userText);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid URL, try again");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `JTextFrame`?what's that?is that your custom component?

Comment: JTextField is what I meant

Comment: Clarity and cleanliness is close to godliness.

Answer (score 3):

Use a FocusListener. On focusGained, select all.

```
  addressBar.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        JTextComponent textComponent = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
        textComponent.selectAll();
     }
  });
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FocusExample extends JPanel {
   private static final int TF_COUNT = 5;
   private JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[TF_COUNT];

   public FocusExample() {
      for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
         textFields[i] = new JTextField("Foo " + (i + 1), 10);
         textFields[i].addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
               JTextComponent textComponent = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
               textComponent.selectAll();
            }
         });
         add(textFields[i]);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      FocusExample mainPanel = new FocusExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FocusExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

This gives the user the option of leaving the previous text in place, of adding to the previous text, or of simply over-writing it by typing.

Comment: This works too, though it will still require the user to delete the text themselves.

Comment: @panoptical: nope, not true. As soon as they start typing, they overwrite the previous text. Try it yourself and see.

Comment: @panoptical: see edited SSCCE. If the user wishes to replace the text, since it is all selected, all they need to do is type. If they wish to keep the current text and add on to it, all they need to do is click again, or use the arrow key.

Answer (score 1):

```
new JTextField("Click & Type Web Address e.g. http://www.google.com");
```

Maybe you want the [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/), which doesn't actually store any text in the text field. It just gives the user a hint what the text field is for.

This is beneficial so that you don't generate DocumentEvents etc., since you are not actually changing the Document.

Answer (score -1):

Add a mouseListener instead of your actionListener method.

```
addressBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    addressBar.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Anyone care to comment what's wrong with this, as opposed to a vote down?

Comment: Sorry, but your advice is bad. This means that your code won't work if the user tabs into the field for example. It's rare that you want to use a MouseListener on a JTextField.

Comment: It's what was asked. OP said "when a user clicks on it".

Comment: I believe that parts needed to loadGo

Comment: Thanks, Hovercraft Full OF Eels (great tag) your help is invaluable.

Comment: -1, I agree with Hovercraft. Any GUI should be designed to work with the mouse or the keyboard. The fact that the question only happens to mention a click should not affect the answer.

Comment: I agree, Hovercraft's answer is better, as most modern browsers are designed to select all text upon the address bar gaining focus. However, that doesn't mean that this answer was, according to SO's own downvote guidelines, "egregiously sloppy or no-effort-expended", and it certainly isn't wrong or incorrect.